# Python Beautiful Soup, saved text not displaying properly in original encoding

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I'm having trouble with a saved file not displaying properly when using it's original encoding.

I'm downloading a web page, searching it for content I want and then writing that content to a file.

The encoding on the site is 'iso-8859-1' or so chrome and beautiful soup tell me and it appears perfectly when viewed using that encoding on the original site.

When I download the page and try to view it however I end up with strange characters (HTML Entities?) like these:

```
â€œ , â€™
```

If I manually set Chromes encoding to 'Utf-8'  when viewing the saved page it appears normally, as does the original page if I set *that* to 'Utf-8'.

I'm not sure what to do with this, I would change the encoding before writing the text to a file but I get ascii errors when I try that.

Here is a sample page (possible adult content):

http://original.adultfanfiction.net/story.php?no=600106516

And the code I am using to get the text from the page:

```
    site = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False)

    html = site.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    rawStory = soup.findAll("td",{"colspan" : '3'})

    story = str(rawStory)

    return story
```

I turn the ResultSet into a string so that I can write it to a file, I don't know if that could be part of the problem, if I print the html to the console after requesting it but before doing anything to it it displays improperly in the console as well.

Comment: Is this Python 2.x or 3.x? The details will be pretty different between the two. (Also, what platform are you on, and what is `sys.getdefaultencoding()`? Those may or may not be relevant, but easier to ask once than a whole chain of questions.)

Comment: Also, are you sure this is your actual code? Because `rawStory` is clearly a `ResultSet`, not a single value, which means calling `str` on it is going to give you a string with extra brackets, commas, and quotes, and all of the non-printable-ASCII characters backslash-escaped (just as if you'd called `repr` on an individual value), so I can't see how it could lead to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 90% sure that your problem is just that you're asking BeautifulSoup for a UTF-8 fragment and then trying to use it as ISO-8859-1, which obviously isn't going to work. The documentation explains all of this pretty nicely.

You're calling `str`. As [Non pretty printing](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing) explains:

> If you just want a string, with no fancy formatting, you can call unicode() or str() on a BeautifulSoup object, or a Tag within it… The `str()` function returns a string encoded in UTF-8.

As [Output encoding](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-encoding) explains:

> When you write out a document from Beautiful Soup, you get a UTF-8 document, even if the document wasn’t in UTF-8 to begin with.

It then follows up with an example of almost exactly what you're doing—parsing a Latin-1 HTML document and writing it back as UTF-8—and then immediately explaining how to fix it:

> If you don’t want UTF-8, you can pass an encoding into prettify()… You can also call encode() on the BeautifulSoup object, or any element in the soup, just as if it were a Python string…

So, that's all you have to do.

---

However, you've got another problem before you get there. When you call `findAll`, you don't get back a tag, you get back a `ResultSet`, which is basically a list of tags. Just as calling `str` on a list of strings gives you brackets, commas, and the repr of each string (with extraneous quotes and backlash escapes for non-printable-ASCII characters) instead of the strings themselves, calling `str` on a `ResultSet` gives you something similar. And you obviously can't call `Tag` methods on a `ResultSet`.

---

Finally, I'm not sure what problem you're actually trying to solve. You're creating a HTML fragment. Ignoring the fact that a fragment isn't a valid document, and browsers shouldn't strictly speaking display it in the first place, it doesn't specify an encoding, meaning the browser can only get that information from some out-of-band place, like you selecting a menu item. Changing it to Latin-1 won't actually "fix" things, it'll just mean that now you get the right display when you pick Latin-1 in the menu and wrong when you pick UTF-8 instead of vice-versa. Why not actually create a full HTML document that actually has a meta http-equiv that actually means what you want it to mean, instead of trying to figure out how to trick Chrome into guessing what you want it to guess?

Comment: I've created an html template and inserted the content into that and it works wonderfully.

For the result set I've gone with getting a string for each item and the adding them together so I don't get the List markers, is that a bad way to do that?

Comment: @DasSnipez: Well, if you have a list of strings, and want to concatenate them, you should just do `''.join(list_of_strings)`. Or, if you have a list of other things, and want to concatenate their string representations, you can do `''.join(map(str, list_of_strings))`. In general, `join` is always better than `+` for concatenating multiple strings. But otherwise, it sounds reasonable.